# Better way to define an array for timeline which can be more generic

Tags: arrays, swift

I have one array of string how can I define it better than current? It is working for me but kind of looks weird.

```
var arrTimelineEntry = ["12 am", "1 am", "2 am", "3 am", "4 am", "5 am", "6 am", "7 am","8 am", "9 am", "10 am", "11 am","12 pm", "1 pm", "2 pm", "3 pm", "4 pm", "5 pm", "6 pm", "7 pm", "8 pm", "9 pm", "10 pm", "11 pm"]
```

Comment: Does the ordering of the string should be as is?

Comment: @AhmadF Yes ordering must be as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you can use `extension` of the `Date` to fetch all day hours like this. And you can customize them also easily for the certain requirements and they are not hardcoded.

```
extension Date {
var startOfDay: Date {
    return Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: self)
}

static func dayHours() -> [String] {
    var hours = [String]()
    var today = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 1492674841).startOfDay

    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale.current
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "h a"
    dateFormatter.amSymbol = "am"
    dateFormatter.pmSymbol = "pm"

    for _ in 0...23 {
        let dateString = dateFormatter.string(from: today )
        hours.append(dateString)
        today.addTimeInterval(3600)
    }

    return hours
}
```

}

Usage:

```
Date.dayHours()
```

Comment: I don't understand this line Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 1492674841).startOfDay. Can you please elaborate the static value passed for the parameter?

Comment: @ParthAdroja this static value is used to avoid DST time and prevent wrong      hour printing.

Answer (score 5):

The following formatter works for different locales and languages.

```
let calendar = Calendar.current
let date = Date() //choose date on which DST never happened

let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = DateFormatter.dateFormat(fromTemplate: "jm", options: 0, locale: NSLocale.current)

let dates = (0...23).map { (hour) in
    return calendar.date(bySettingHour: hour, minute: 0, second: 0, of: date)!
}

let timeLine = dates.map(formatter.string)
```

Comment: Works with your answer too. Thanks.

Comment: salabaha, this is a good answer (it's localized, unlike the other answers here). But it has a problem that it won't work properly on days that "spring forward" for daylight savings (e.g. March 11th, 2018, in the US). Rather than using `Date()`, you might want to use a date on which you know that daylight savings adjustments cannot take place.